# MySQL Same database two host Replace Into

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two databases in MySQL on the same server which means hostname is same.

I want to use the REPLACE INTO statement to replace data in DB1 with data in DB2.

The concern is that both databases has different login credentials.

Kindly advice how can I do that?

Regards,
Kalpesh

Answer (score 1):

You will need an account that has the appropriate access to both databases. After that, you can use the database name before the table names to specify which table to use.

```
REPLACE INTO Database1.Table1(A, B, C)
SELECT A, B, C
FROM Database2.Table1
```

With two different accounts this won't work, but the accounts are created per server, so you may create a different account for this purpose, or grant one of the existing accounts access to the other database.

If it is not possible to get such an account, I think the only option is to export the table from the first database, import it in the second database under a different name, and then run the statement on the imported table.